# C# Selenium cannot find title after opening PDF link

Tags: c#, selenium

I made a simple Selenium test to click on a PDF link and then verify that the title of the page is correct. I'm running this in Google Chrome, and on inspecting the page I can see that it has a title (XPath: /html/head/title).

However, the test is failing because driver.Title is always an empty string, and when I try to find the title/head of the page with the XPath I get a NoSuchElementException. On the backend, it's just a route that returns a file:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
{
   ...
   return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

The link opens a new tab, but I've navigated to other pages in the tab and was able to verify that driver.Title was not an empty string. I also tried waiting, but I still wasn't able to find the title. The page is just a head and a body with a pdf-viewer. I haven't seen anyone else having issues with finding the Title blank, except for a Firefox compatibility issue. As a workaround I'm just checking the url, but I would rather check the title to make sure that the page is loading. I'm just not sure why the driver isn't able to find it.

Comment: I take it the PDF is opening up inside the Chrome browser window?

Comment: Yes, does that stop Selenium from reading it like a normal webpage?

Comment: Maybe. A PDF is not an HTML document, so the browser might be using a different component to display the PDF, and might be something Selenium cannot interact with. Inspect element on the PDF and see if that is even available as an option in the right-click context menu.

Comment: When I inspect the page it looks like a pretty normal html page, with an html, head, and body tags. The title is inside the head where I'd expect it to be and contains the expected text. It looks normal, but it must not be since Selenium can't interact with it normally.
 <html><head><title>Target</title></head><body></body></html>